# I want to test my React Native app (Ejected from Expo as Bare Workflow) on an android device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, nativeapplication

I am working on an android application (project) with react-native but I got stuck and want to know how can I run it on my android device in the Expo client app. I have built the app with the android studio but I need a fast refresh. So I want to know how can I run it on the expo client android app. Please Help.

**Thanks For Helping.**